# Calling another program to run inside my program in IDL

Tags: call, wrapper, idl-programming-language

The program I am calling is called modeltest pro and my program is called wrapp.pro. I am just curious as to how to call modeltest pro to my program so that my program wrapps around modeltest.pro? I am new to programing, so any information would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a read of this: http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/physics/ASTR201/IDLTutorial/tutorial_03.html

in IDL procedures are called using the following syntax:

```
myprocedure, input
```

So in your case you would just use inside wrapp.pro (assuming theres no inputs):

```
modeltest
```

but be sure that modeltest is defined as a procedure, the extension (.pro) does not mean it is a procedure. The file must be formatted as:

```
pro modeltest

#code here

end
```